# OrmLite foreign key exists from Json

Tags: android, ormlite

I've never used OrmLite before but I need to edit an existing project that uses it.

I have two classes : Person and Office.

I'm using gson to parse, with the person an office Id is provided, for example office_id: "4456".

I was hoping it would be possible to link the two together from my Person class so I can easily get a office for a person.

For example:

```
@SerializedName("id")
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = ID)
private int mId;

@SerializedName("full_name")
@DatabaseField(columnName = FULL_NAME)
private String mFullName = null;

@DatabaseField(columnName = POSITION)
private String mPosition = null;

@SerializedName("email")
@DatabaseField(columnName = EMAIL)
private String mEmail = null;

private Office office = null;

@SerializedName("office_id")
private String officeId = null;
```

So I have the officeId from Json which is stored in the Person table.  I would like to automatically load the Office into the Person object whenever it is loaded.

Comment: So you want to load the office object automatically when you load a person from the db?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want

Comment: I would like to do it with the office id provided in the json

Comment: And that id is already stored in the person table?

Comment: Yeah, I have office_id provided by the json, so I can put OfficeId into the person table.  The question is then how to use this to load the office object automatically when I load a person.  I'll try to clarify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically fetch a referenced object upon querying you can use `foreignAutoRefresh = true` in your `@DatabaseField`. You reference the Object and not the id itself. In the table, the id of the referenced row will be stored.

To clarify for your project:
`Office` must look something like this:

```
@SerializedName("id")
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = ID)
private int mId;

...
```

And your `Person` (database-wise) like this:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = ID)
private int mId;

@DatabaseField(columnName = FULL_NAME)
private String mFullName = null;

@DatabaseField(columnName = POSITION)
private String mPosition = null;

@DatabaseField(columnName = EMAIL)
private String mEmail = null;

@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Office office = null;
```

The `Office` column in the `Person` table will hold the `id` of the `Office`.

`foreignAutoRefresh` tells ORMLite to fetch the full `Office` upon querying the `Person`
http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#foreignAutoRefresh()

Hope this helps

Comment: Heya, so does this mean I when I create my DAE's I must manually set the Office object on the person (person.setOffice(Office) in order to set this relationship?  I.e the relationship cannot be formed from a String id provided by the json?

Comment: I think you'll have to create and set the Office object the way you described. At the moment I can't think of another way to have this done automatically.